# ImportError: No module named Cython.Debugger?

Tags: python, cython

I got this error When i was debugging the cython code use cygdb on windows10. Here is the detail. Can anyone help me?

resemble.pyx

```
cdef int _resemble(str s1, str s2):
    cdef int count = 0
    cdef int len_s1 = len(s1)
    cdef int len_s2 = len(s2)
    cdef float bound = 0.5*(max(len_s1, len_s2))
    cdef int index1, index2
    cdef str item1, item2
    for index1 in range(len_s1):
        item1 = s1[index1]
        for index2 in range(len_s2):
            item2 = s2[index2]
            if item1 == item2 and abs(index2 - index1) < bound:
                count += 1
    return count


def resemble(s1, s2):
    return _resemble(s1, s2)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = (Extension('resemble', ["resemble.pyx"]))
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, gdb_debug=True))
```

test.py

```
import resemble

r = resemble.resemble("dfefgeg,fre", "wff.fefre")
print(r)
```

cmd

```
cython --gdb resemble.pyx
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
cygdb
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Cython.Debugger
```

Comment: is your gdb compiled with python 2.x or 3.x? It must be built with 2.x for cygdb to work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000039/importerror-no-module-named-cython-debugger) and the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cygdb ImportError: No module named 'Cython'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407916/cygdb-importerror-no-module-named-cython)